# How do I disable the Safari cross origin request for Ipad/Iphone on browser stack?

Tags: selenium, browserstack, safaridriver

I am running my UI automation tests on browser stack and they all are failing just for Ipad/Iphone safari browser running on ios 11.

Our application is making cross domain requests and this could be one of the reasons why ios restricts it. Hence is there any way in browser stack I can disable this policy via capabilities or setting some preferneces?

Answer (score 0):

The issue you are referring to is already raised with Appium and is specific to Safari iOS and Appium. Here are the issues for your reference:

- https://github.com/appium/appium/issues/5832
- https://github.com/appium/appium/issues/9464
- https://github.com/appium/appium/issues/10184